# How can I download link from YahooFinance in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

currently I'm trying to automatically scrape/download yahoo finance historical data. I plan to download the data using the download link provided in the website.
[image: CSV download URL]

My code is to list all the available link and work it from there, the problem is that the exact link doesn't appear in the result. Here is my code(partial):

```
def scrape_page(url, header):
     page = requests.get(url, headers=header)
     if page.status_code == 200:
         soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
         return soup
     return null
if __name__ == '__main__':
     symbol = 'GOOGL'
     
     dt_start = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=(365*5+1))
     dt_end = datetime.today()
    
     start = format_date(dt_start)
     end = format_date(dt_end)
     
     sub = subdomain(symbol, start, end)
     header = header_function(sub)
     
     base_url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com'
     url = base_url + sub

     soup = scrape_page(url, header)
     result = soup.find_all('a')
     for a in result:
          print('URL :',a['href'])
```

UPDATE 10/9/2020 :
I managed to find the span which is the parent for the link with this code

```
spans = soup.find_all('span',{"class":"Fl(end) Pos(r) T(-6px)"})
```

However, when I print it out, it does not show the link, here is the output:

```
>>> spans
[<span class="Fl(end) Pos(r) T(-6px)" data-reactid="31"></span>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. That link is generated by javascript and requests.get() method won't work on dynamic content. I switched to selenium to download that link.

Answer (score 0):

To download the historical data in CSV format from Yahoo Finance, you can use this example:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime


csv_link = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{quote}?period1={from_}&period2={to_}&interval=1d&events=history'

quote = 'GOOGL'
from_ = str(datetime.timestamp(datetime(2019,9,27,0,0))).split('.')[0]
to_ = str(datetime.timestamp(datetime(2020,9,27,23,59))).split('.')[0]

print(requests.get(csv_link.format(quote=quote, from_=from_, to_=to_)).text)
```

Prints:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
2019-09-27,1242.829956,1244.989990,1215.199951,1225.949951,1225.949951,1706100
2019-09-30,1220.599976,1227.410034,1213.420044,1221.140015,1221.140015,1223500
2019-10-01,1222.489990,1232.859985,1205.550049,1206.000000,1206.000000,1225200
2019-10-02,1196.500000,1198.760010,1172.630005,1177.920044,1177.920044,1651500
2019-10-03,1183.339966,1191.000000,1163.140015,1189.430054,1189.430054,1418400
2019-10-04,1194.290039,1212.459961,1190.969971,1210.959961,1210.959961,1214100
2019-10-07,1207.000000,1218.910034,1204.359985,1208.250000,1208.250000,852000
2019-10-08,1198.770020,1206.869995,1189.479980,1190.130005,1190.130005,1004300
2019-10-09,1201.329956,1208.459961,1198.119995,1202.400024,1202.400024,797400
2019-10-10,1198.599976,1215.619995,1197.859985,1209.469971,1209.469971,642100
2019-10-11,1224.030029,1228.750000,1213.640015,1215.709961,1215.709961,1116500
2019-10-14,1213.890015,1225.880005,1211.880005,1217.770020,1217.770020,664800
2019-10-15,1221.500000,1247.130005,1220.920044,1242.239990,1242.239990,1379200
2019-10-16,1241.810059,1254.189941,1238.530029,1243.000000,1243.000000,1149300
2019-10-17,1251.400024,1263.750000,1249.869995,1252.800049,1252.800049,1047900
2019-10-18,1254.689941,1258.109985,1240.140015,1244.410034,1244.410034,1581200
2019-10-21,1248.699951,1253.510010,1239.989990,1244.280029,1244.280029,904700
2019-10-22,1244.479980,1248.729980,1239.849976,1241.199951,1241.199951,1143100
2019-10-23,1240.209961,1258.040039,1240.209961,1257.630005,1257.630005,1064100
2019-10-24,1259.109985,1262.900024,1252.349976,1259.109985,1259.109985,1011200

...and so on.
```

Comment: Well, i did think of that. However, if the url format changes, I have to modify the URL. Moreover, I can't resuse the code for other stuff. My aim is to get that URL from webscraping so I can download it.